# Vetor ordem crescente c#

Tags: c#

Como colocar números impares em ordem crescente?

```
int c = 0;
int[] numeros = { 10, 5, 20, 60, 1, 5, 8, 30, 11, 20, 25, 30, 50 };
Console.Write("Números pares");
foreach (int num in numeros)
{
    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(num + ", ");
    }
    else
    {
        c += num;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("\n Soma dos numeros impares " + c);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom o titulo da sua questao diz que quer ordenar o vetor. Mas o código postado imprime os pares e soma os impares. Segue uma resposta ao que foi perguntado, ordenação de um vetor de *int*. Caso queira colocar somente os impares em ordem crescente, segue a logica de separa-los e coloque-os em uma lista depois utilize este  `Array.Sort(numeros);` para ordenar.

```
    int[] numeros = { 10, 5, 20, 60, 1, 5, 8, 30, 11, 20, 25, 30, 50 };
    Console.Write("Números ordenados");
    Array.Sort(numeros);
    // Escrevendo array
    foreach (int i in numeros) Console.Write(i + " ");
```

**Seguindo o seu código**, para somente ordenar os impares ficaria assim:

```
    int c = 0;
    List numeros = new List(){ 10, 5, 20, 60, 1, 5, 8, 30, 11, 20, 25, 30, 50 };
    List impares = new List();
    Console.Write("Números pares");
    foreach (int num in numeros)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write(num + ", ");
        }
        else
        {
           impares.Add(num);
        }
    }
    Array.Sort(impares);
    Console.WriteLine("\n numeros impares ordenados");
    foreach (int ordImp in impares)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ordImp);
    }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra alterativa é usar o `Linq` que fica bem compacta:

```
int[] numeros = { 10, 5, 20, 60, 1, 5, 8, 30, 11, 20, 25, 30, 50 };
int[] numerosImparesOrdenados = numeros.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();

foreach(var numero in numerosImparesOrdenados)
{
     Console.WriteLine(numero);
}
```

No `Linq` usei o `Where` para filtras os ímpares, depois o `OrderBy` para ordenar em ordem crescente, e no final, `ToArray` para retornar um novo array.

Aqui tem um exemplo funcionando: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vgx580)